# Why does my error message display quickly, then disappear right away

Tags: xpages

I have a save button on my xpage.  I have field edits inside of the button.  I did that because when I put the edit in the field validation, it runs when I open a new xpage.  Either way though, I have an Error Message control on the form.  When I click the save button, it flashes yellow then disappears.  Why is this occurring?  It's simple code:

```
if(getComponent("ExpAmt").getValue() == null) {
    @WarningMessage("You must enter an Amount for this expense");
    return false;
}
```

Partial refresh message box displays saying:

An error occurred while updating some of the page.
Unable to load http://localhost/DB.nsf/xpForm.xsp?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id3%3A_id4%3ApanelAll status: 0

Comment: Are you doing a full or partial refresh when the code runs?

Comment: I've tried both and every combination of things I can think of.

Comment: For some reason, the partial now works.  I refresh the entire form inside a "panelAll" panel but it works.

Comment: Spoke too soon.  Only in one xpage does it work.  All the others it doesn't, just flashes

Comment: Can you post the full code?  I'd be interested to see if it could be recreated.

Comment: The full code for what, the entire xpage form or the save button?  I also get the message above (I'll try to add it to my original question) when I do a partial refresh on panelAll which is everything on the xpage form.  If I do a full refresh, this message does not appear but the error message still flashes.

Comment: Error message code: <xp:messages id="messages1" style="text-align:left"></xp:messages> ******************* Button code: if(getComponent("OrderDate").getValue() == null) {
  @WarningMessage("You must enter an Order Date");
  return;
}
viewScope.vsMG1 = getComponent("BillContact").getValue()
if(getComponent("BillContact").getValue() == "") {
  @WarningMessage("You must enter a Contact Name");
  return;
}
document1.save();

Comment: I have a demo DB I created with one form that does this that I sent to Knut Herrmann to see.  He went on holiday though.  Give me your email and I can send it....

Comment: firstname at rbmcs.org is my email address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a partial refresh in your ccApplicationLayout that runs onClientLoad.  It was immediately refreshing the panel after the page was loaded which caused the flashing effect.  Removing this solved the issue.

Comment: Rob you're great!!!!!!  I didn't even realize that was there and was not looking there to figure it out.  It works, however, I also have this box flash up when doing a partial refresh on other parts of the xpage including the error messages.  The error is above in the original question.  Can you shed some light on it?  I tried changing the name of panelAll in the layout since I have that name also on custom controls.  Didn't change the box flashing.

Comment: Mike, the error is complaining that the panelAll id is not present so, try searching for partialRefreshId="panelAll" in your design.  You could also get some better details on what is erroring if you checked the logs.  There is an OpenNTF project that makes reading the logs easier.  https://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=opendocument&name=xpages%20log%20file%20reader You would need to put the code on the server for this to be a help though